# Expiration of accreditation of the program

Tags: graduate-school

In the university Master degree transcript, if it is written that accreditation of program is valid until Jan 10, 2016, then what does that imply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **For you, who hold the degree: nothing**. Your degree does not have an expiration date. It will remain valid for all uses after Jan 10, 2016.
- For the department: if they want to continue enrolling students in this program and handing out this degree, they will have to renew their accreditation. This means justifying to a local or national regulating body (depending on the country and local law) the value of the degree, the seriousness of the degree-granting process, and many other such assurances.